# Is reassignment not changing value of const in java script?

Tags: javascript

Please clarify this silly doubt:

```
for (let count = 0; count < 3 && count < players.length; count++) { 
  const num = count + 1  
  const player = players[count] 
  console.log(`${num}. ${player}`) 
}
```

Here const num= count+1;
isnot new value (primitive)being assigned to count in each iteration.
or const num is allowed as it ll create new variable with same name discarding old var 
const num=0;
num=count+1 will be invalid i understand but can some one explain above doubt.

Comment: New values are assigned to the `count` variables in `count++`, and that works because `count` is declared with `let`. Yes, each iteration has its own block-scoped `num`, and that variable stays constant.

Comment: You're right. `const num = count + 1` will create a **new** constant variable, bound to the block scope of the for  loop, on each iteration. The old variable will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you create new `const num` in each iteration, that is mean you are not changing existed variable. There is could other case when you have `const num` before the loop, then you can't change it in the loop, so you should use let. It's better use const for primitive values.